# Shell script error handling

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm cleaning the output of my scripts. For example:

```
rm -f ./file
```

> No such file or directory

I want to implement some error checking for this command, equivalent to a `try/catch` statement. In other words, I want to catch the error if the command fails.

Comment: `rm -f blahblahblah` does not print an error message on my system.  Does it on yours?  What system?

Comment: just a hint: search for `set -e`, `trap`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use a simple script?

```
file=$1
if [ ! -f $file ]; then
    echo "File not found!"
else 
    rm -f $file
fi
```

When you run it, the script will tell you whether a given file does not exist.

You can also redirect to both `stderr` and `stdout` by using `2>&1` after the echo command. You may also add an `exit 1` at the end of the if statement, because an exit status of 1 generally indicates that the command was not executed successfully.

This will not work in the exact way as you intend it to, but in bash this is the closest way of detecting errors.

Answer (score 4):

Python:

```
try:
    os.remove('./file')
    champagne_for_everybody
except:
    throw_myself_in_the_river
```

Shell:

```
if rm ./file
then
    champagne_for_everybody
else
    throw_myself_in_the_river
fi
```

Notes:

- Don't use `-f` - [POSIX `rm`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/rm.html) ignores missing files when using `-f`.
- Don't use shell if you can avoid it. Python and other modern languages have *much* more sophisticated error handling built in.

Answer (score 2):

use `set -e` or you can achive same behaviour using `&&` or `||`